# Stop words not being correctly removed from string

Tags: java, replace, stop-words

I have a function which reads stop words from a file and saves it in a HashSet.

```
HashSet<String> hset = readFile();
```

This is my string

```
String words = "the plan crash is invisible";
```

I am trying to remove all the stop words from the string but it is not working correctly

**The output i am getting:** plan crash  invible

**Output i want =>** plan crash invisible

Code:

```
HashSet<String> hset = readFile();
        String words = "the plan crash is invisible";

        String s = words.toLowerCase();

        String[] split = s.split(" ");
        for(String str: split){
            if (hset.contains(str)) {

                s = s.replace(str, "");

            } else {

            }

        }

        System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + s);
```

Comment: try with equals() or equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: And you should not use `replace` because it will remove the "is" in invisible when you try to remove the whole word "is". Or at least you should change the way you use it to make sure it only remove whole words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `hset.contains(str)` matches full words, `s.replace(str, "");` can replace occurrences of the "stop" words which are part of words of the input `String`. Hence "inv**is**ible" becomes "invible".

Since you are iterating over all the words of `s` anyway, you can construct a `String` that contains all the words not contained in the `Set`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String str: split){
    if (!hset.contains(str)) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(str);
    }
}
System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + sb.toString());
```

Comment: @litelite Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

No need so check if your string contain the stop word or split your string, you can use `replaceAll` which use regex, like this :

```
for (String str : hset) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s" + str + "|" + str + "\\s", " ");
}
```

---

**Excample :**

```
HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<>();
hset.add("is");
hset.add("the");

String words = "the plan crash is invisible";

String s = words.toLowerCase();

for (String str : hset) {
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s" + str + "|" + str + "\\s", " ");
}
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();//comment and idea of @davidxxx
System.out.println(s);
```

This can gives you :

```
plan crash invisible
```

Comment: The idea is interesting but I think that the whitespace handling that may be before or after and also multiple is harder to handle with a regex. For example in your case, you have a whitespace that is not required in the output

Comment: thank you @davidxxx yes this is correct i think i need to use `trim()` and `replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` checl my answer now :) thank youuu